# How can I understand FPGA?

Tags: fpga, stm32

I am learning Embedded programming. I already have the STM32F407 board. And there are many things to figure out.

However, I've heard of FPGAs, and am wondering exactly what they are. Are they a separate peripheral like USART or I2C or group of peripherals?

I've already read many things on this, but it still is not quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

An FPGA is a Field Programmable Gate Array. This is a completely separate device from the microcontroller you have. See [FPGA in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPGA)

An FPGA basically enables you to create any kind of logic using VHDL or Verilog language. You can combine digital gates and other elements to create any type of digital logic, even a microprocessor (called soft core processor). The STM32 device you have is a 32-bit microcontroller that has already been implemented and configured with a fixed set of peripherals. It is a general processor and cannot reconfigure its hardware the way an FPGA can.

In the last few years, the lines have blurred more and more since hard core ARM processors have been integrated into FPGAs so that you can take advantage of both general purpose processor and generating your own hardware logic.

Other relevant links:

[ARM Cortex-M3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M3#Cortex-M3)

Comment: On my board, there is SPARTAN-6 (XILINX). Is it FPGA or other thing?

Comment: Absolutely. It's a pretty powerful FPGA. I hadn't realized that was the case. Do you have a link to the board user guide? The FPGA may be used for different things. Usually when it's paired with a microcontroller, it helps offload heavy processing tasks and leaves the microcontroller do the management itself. Again, it depends on what the board does (although you could still use it for things like creating your own peripherals).

Comment: I just realized that my board is not standard. Because we are now working on project based on wireless communication. I think this board is based on STM32F407 (because we are that board`s documentations). There are WM8976G audio codec, SPARATN-6 (XILINX) and other things on board. (maybe I am mistaking)